# UPSERT fails for INSERT expression with SELECT

Tags: sqlite, upsert

I ran into a problem with the UPSERT statement in SQLite.
I have a master and a slave database, the updates to the slave database should be merged into the master database. I would like to use the UPSERT clause. This works for inserting `values()` but not for inserting from a subquery.

The documentation (at least the diagram) shows that it should work: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

But I'm getting an error. Am I missing something?

```
sqlite> create table orig (id int unique, a int);
sqlite> create table copy (id int unique, a int);
sqlite> insert into orig values (1,0);
sqlite> insert into copy values (1,0);
sqlite> insert into orig values (1,1) on conflict do update set a=1;
sqlite> select * from orig;
1|1
sqlite> insert into orig select * from copy on conflict do update set a=2;
Parse error: near "do": syntax error
  insert into orig select * from copy on conflict do update set a=2;
                                    error here ---^
```

I also have tried different expressions, but no avail:

```
sqlite> insert into orig select * from copy on conflict do nothing;
Parse error: near "do": syntax error
  insert into orig select * from copy on conflict do nothing;
                                    error here ---^
sqlite> insert into orig select * from copy on conflict (id) do update set a=2;
Parse error: near "do": syntax error
  ert into orig select * from copy on conflict (id) do update set a=2;
                                      error here ---^
```

`sqlite3 --version 3.40.1 2022-12-28`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the Parsing Ambiguity section of the manual's [entry on UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html):

> ### 2.2. Parsing Ambiguity
>
> When the INSERT statement to which the UPSERT is attached takes its values from a SELECT statement, there is a potential parsing ambiguity. The parser might not be able to tell if the "ON" keyword is introducing the UPSERT or if it is the ON clause of a join. To work around this, the SELECT statement should always include a WHERE clause, even if that WHERE clause is just "WHERE true".
>
> Ambiguous use of ON:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2
> ON CONFLICT(x) DO UPDATE SET y=excluded.y;
> ```
>
> Ambiguity resolved using a WHERE clause:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE true
> ON CONFLICT(x) DO UPDATE SET y=excluded.y;
> ```

Therefore, in order to resolve your issue, you need to add the redundant `where true` just before the upsert's `on`:

```
insert into orig
select * from copy
where true  -- <<< this guy here
on conflict do update set a=2;
```

[Live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FfosD_NJ)

Comment: Super, many thanks! RT *Full* M…
Indeed I did test a statement with WHERE, and it didn't work because of an different error.